# How do I count the number of filled-in rows of a sheet based on the contents of a column?

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

Disclaimer: I am completely self-taught in google sheets

I have a sheet with columns for *Date, Place, Title,* etc. I am attempting to count how many rows have all their cells filled out, but only want to add up the rows within a certain time period (i.e. based on the "date" cells, which are column A.)

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(AND(
                      ISBETWEEN(A9:A,DATE(2022,1,21),DATE(2022,4,1)),
                      ISTEXT(B9:B)=ISTEXT(C9:C)=ISTEXT(D9:D)=TRUE)))
```

Currently I have **this** formula, which relies on an "AND" function to check that both the "ISBETWEEN" and "ISTEXT" criteria are met. However, I think this is keeping "ARRAYFORMULA" from working (I originally used "SUMPRODUCT", but that didn't work either.) If that isn't the problem, the fact that the different references aren't somehow logically connected makes wonder if this would method would even work to begin with...
So, what functions could I use to accomplish my goal?

I would prefer to contain all of this in one formula, but at this point I'd be fine utilizing a separate hidden sheet if what I'm doing isn't possible in just one cell.

(I've done my best to try and find if this has already been asked, but honestly I'm not sure how to properly phrase this, so sorry if this is a duplicate.)

Comment: could you share a sample sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(B9:B; B9:B<>""; C9:C<>""; D9:D<>"", 
 A9:A>="2022-1-21*1"; A9:A<="2022-4-1"*1))
```

[image]

or use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B9:B100<>""; C9:C100<>""; D9:D100<>""; 
 A9:A100>="2022-1-21"*1; A9:A100<="2022-4-1"*1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I can follow the logic of this formula, however, it doesn't work. I've made multiple test sheets to make sure that the issue isn't just with my specific data, and in all of them, this always just returns "0". Have you been able to use this successfully in a sheet?

Comment: @Gold_Currency can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: here's an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRToPi4sbO8olu6D4TucJWOFpm-seuzQNnT6r5s9LFMQlu055_4pTjaC9tYLMT9cJ3af2Z8ZKfJUR1u/pub?output=xlsx

Comment: @Gold_Currency answer updated

Comment: the new equations work, thanks so much! Out of interest, do you know why multiplying the dates by 1 makes the logic work?

Comment: @Gold_Currency dates are stored in numeric value format so plain text date multiplied by 1 will convert text string into numeric value